# string to array, array to <ul> using javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to take a user entered string. Create an array from said string. Then take that array and display it as a 'ul'. The user entered string will be flower names separated by "&". I would also like to see if I could use an alert to notify the user that they basically did not type in a correctly formatted string.

here is what I have so far but Im confused at how to continue as well as how to implement an "alert".

html:

```
    <form>
        Enter flowers here: <input type="text" id="flower_string"><br>
        <input type="button" value="Just Do It" onclick="FlowerArray()"><br>
    </form>
    <ul id="flower_results"></ul>
```

javascript:

```
//funtion will take user flower names seperated by "&" to create an array and display
function FlowerArray(){
    var flower_string = document.getElementById("flower_string").value;
    var flower_array = flower_string.split("&");
    var i;
    //for loop to display results to user
    for(i = 0; i < flower_array.length; i++){

    }
}
```

my for loop is not complete because im unsure how i can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create `<li>` elements and append them to the `<ul>`.
See this snippet with comments:

```js
//funtion will take user flower names seperated by "&" to create an array and display
function FlowerArray(){
  var flower_string = document.getElementById("flower_string").value;
  var flower_array = flower_string.split("&");
  var i;
  var results = document.getElementById('flower_results'); // <- get the UL element
  //for loop to display results to user
  for(i = 0; i < flower_array.length; i++){
    var li = document.createElement('li'); // <- create a LI element
    li.innerHTML = flower_array[i]; // <- set it's content
    results.appendChild(li); // append it to the UL
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
Enter flowers here: <input type="text" id="flower_string"><br>
<input type="button" value="Just Do It" onclick="FlowerArray()"><br>
</form>
<ul id="flower_results"></ul>
```

Comment: I would use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` to avoid parsing the string as HTML.

Comment: @Oriol that's only true if the content really is just text. I'm not assuming anything about what styling / HTML OP really wants to put inside the `<li>`'s.

Answer (score 2):

You can compose a string and the append it as innerHTML:

```js
function FlowerArray() {
  var flower_string = document.getElementById("flower_string").value;
  var flower_array = flower_string.split("&");
  var i, html = '';
  
  //for loop to display results to user
  html = flower_array.map(function(el) {
    return '<li>' + el + '</li>';
  }).join('');
  
  document.getElementById('flower_results').innerHTML = html;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Enter flowers here:
  <input type="text" id="flower_string">
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="Just Do It" onclick="FlowerArray()">
  <br>
</form>
<ul id="flower_results"></ul>
```